# Google apps login file

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

In google app engine, there is file called login. I need to modify this login file. It is in my local host, but I can't find out where it is stored.

Can anybody help me to find the solution?

Comment: blooded: I fixed your spelling and grammar, but you are going to have to provide more information in order to get a helpful answer. Specifically? What kind of a file is `login`? Is it `login.html` or `login.py`? Is your computer's directory search capability unable to find the location of this file? What are you hoping to accomplish through modifying it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to `/_ah/login`, this is a stub page provided by the development server to represent the Google Accounts sign in page you will see in production. The sign in page in prod is not under your control, so there would be little point in modifying the dev version.

If you'd like to design your own login page, consider using Federated Login or a custom authentication library not integrated with Google Accounts.